# Mysql PHP File upload update

Tags: php, mysql, crud

I have the following code from update.php. Create.php works just fine. When I try to update the query by ID I don't see the image file on update.php so I have to upload the file again. How can I solve this problem. I have a upload folder where I upload the images and save the random generated file name into database.

```
    $officer = $_POST['officer'];
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $complaint = $_POST['complaint'];
    $injured_name = $_POST['injured_name'];
    $owner_name = $_POST['owner_name'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];       

    //To be able to upload file to 'uploads/' folder all file related files. 
    $file = rand(1000,100000)."-".$_FILES['file']['name'];
    $file_loc = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
    $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
    $folder="uploads/";

    // new file size in KB
    $new_size = $file_size/1024;  
    // new file size in KB
    // make file name in lower case
    $new_file_name = strtolower($file);
    // make file name in lower case

    $final_file=str_replace(' ','-',$new_file_name);



        $pdo = Database::connect();
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $sql = "UPDATE incidents SET officer = ?, date = ?, complaint =?, injured_name = ?, owner_name =?, description =?, file =?, type =?, size =?) WHERE id =?";
        $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $q->execute(array($officer, $date, $complaint, $injured_name, $owner_name, $description, $final_file, $file_type, $new_size, $id));
        Database::disconnect();
        header("Location: incidents.php");

     }

 else {
    $pdo = Database::connect();
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM incidents where id = ?";
    $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array($id));
    $data = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $officer = $data['officer'];
    $date = $data['date'];
    $complaint = $data['complaint'];
    $injured_name = $data['injured_name'];
    $owner_name = $data['owner_name'];
    $description = $data['description'];
    $file = $data['file'];

    Database::disconnect();
}
```

And my form is

```
    <div class="field">
                    <label class="upload" for="uploads">
                        <div class="btn">

                            <input name="file" placeholder="file upload" type="file" id="file" required value="<?php echo !empty($file)?$file:'';?>"/></div>
                    </label>
                </div>
```

I am new to PHP so please forgive me if there is a simple solution. I appreciate for your help. Thanks

Comment: do you have write permission to your folder where you uploading your images ?

Comment: yes I do. I can upload the files through Create.php

Comment: I don't know if it's just a typo error, but you have an unnecessary `)` in your first query. Also make sure you have the `<form enctype="multipart/form-data"> ... </form>` tags.

Comment: Dan You are right about the extra ')' I removed it but it is still not working. Form already has enctype="multipart/form-data"

Comment: i can not find `move_uploaded_file()` in your code, can you tell me in which line you're trying to move file to directory ?

Comment: <form action="update.php?id=<?php echo $id?>"  id="questionnaire" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Comment: move_uploaded_file() I don't think I have that anywhere in my code

Comment: DivYank is move_uploaded_file() necessary to update???

Answer (score 0):

you are required to move the file if you are uploading it. Then in your database you set the new name of the uploaded file (Update).

```
$final_file=str_replace(' ','-',$new_file_name);
// moving the file.
move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$folder . $final_file);
```

Comment: well I need to file information display on the file upload area first. Right now even I need to update the officer's name I also have to upload the image again because it doesn't show the file information. I can see the information on the database and file is uploaded to folder.